# I tried to run server on my laravel file is having issues with vendor/autoload.php on Windows

Tags: php, laravel-8

When i type "php atisan",it prints:
PHP Warning:  require(C:\Windows\System32\myproject\learn/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Windows\System32\myproject\learn\artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\Windows\System32\myproject\learn/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Windows\System32\myproject\learn\artisan:18
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in C:\Windows\System32\myproject\learn\artisan on line 18

I type "composer update --no-scripts" it prints:
Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- laravel/framework[v9.11.0, ..., 9.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^3.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.0.0, ..., 3.x-dev].
- league/flysystem[3.0.0, ..., 3.x-dev] require league/mime-type-detection ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.11.0].
- league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.0] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.1.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
- league/mime-type-detection[1.4.0, ..., 1.11.0] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^9.11 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v9.11.0, 9.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\PHP\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

Comment: Execute "composer install" then try again

Comment: I already did that

Comment: I already did that

Answer (score 2):

if your project doesn't have a vendor folder try to install composer via `composer install`, if vendor folder exist and some required modules are missing you should have to update the composer via `composer update`

after you are done with composer, should have a environment file, the default environment file will be named as `.env.example`. you have to rename it as `.env`

when you have an enviroment file in your project laravel requered to have a application key inorder to start the development key, so you will be able to generate on via `php artisan key:generate`

you are ready to start the development server via `php artisan serve`, which will starts the development server on `port 8000`. if the port `8000` not work on your server you can start the development server with other ports via `php artisan serve --port=45600`

Comment: that's a good idea

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;**
Make sure your server has [all requirements needed](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/deployment#server-requirements) to run your version of Laravel.

**Long Answer:**
Composer is giving you clear instructions of what is wrong. Here is the snippet of the Composer output you provided (formatted):

```
Loading composer repositories with package information Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine Updating dependencies Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
- laravel/framework[v9.11.0, ..., 9.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^3.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.0.0, ..., 3.x-dev].
- league/flysystem[3.0.0, ..., 3.x-dev] require league/mime-type-detection ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.11.0].
- league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.0] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.1.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
- league/mime-type-detection[1.4.0, ..., 1.11.0] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension. 
- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^9.11 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v9.11.0, 9.x-dev].
```

This means that Composer wants to install the package called *"laravel/framework"*. That package then requires *"league/flysystem"*, which then requires *"league/mime-type-detection"*.

This is where we get to the root of your issue. Package "league/mime-type-detection" can not be installed because you are missing the PHP ext-fileinfo extension. You need to install that extension on your PHP server and confirm it is installed before trying to *composer install* again.

Comment: How do i get it installed

Comment: @GodwinTobi Depends on what server you are using for running PHP on your Windows machine. Searching the name of the server and "install php fileinfo" should give relevant results.